# populating multi-table inherited models in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-profiles

I am using models in following way:

```
class UserProfile:
# Some Stuff

class CompanyProfile(UserProfile):
# Some more stuff

class CandidateProfile(UserProfile):
# Even more stuff
```

mean CompanyProfile and CandidateProfile are inheriting from UserProfile . How will I populate these CompanyProfile and CandidateProfile from  whether registrationform and from another profileform? How will I tell it that which profile I am creating a user or entering data?

Comment: @Adam yes, this question is older one and have now figured it out, will post answer in few hours here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in following way that is in another thread on stackoverflow.com here : [django user profile creation,set user profile while using multiple profile types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374071/django-profile-creation-set-user-profile-while-using-multiple-profile-types) , code is following:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
if commit:
    user.save()
    person = Person(user=user)
    person.full_name = self.cleaned_data["fullname"]
    person.save()
return user
```